# Linked entity forgets its ID on edit in Core causing error - needs to be kept in an invisible controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using the new feature of owned entity. On create it works great because the ID is null'ish but doesn't collide with anything, just getting assigned automatically when saving. However, when I execute edit, the principal and owned entities are sent end rendered but can't be saved.

I investigated the issue and it turns out that the owned entity comes back with null'ish ID (despite that it's been sent to the client with its ID). My conclusion is that it gets forgotten because there's no field binding to it.

My idea is to have a hidden field to keep the value in the page's model. The question is how I do that.

The other question is if it's such a great idea or just an ugly hack and, if so, what might be done instead.

```
public class Main
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Owned Owned { get; set; }
}

public class Owned
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Phone { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Add your owned entity mode class please?

Comment: @TanvirArjel Done, as requested.

Comment: "My idea is to have a hidden field to keep the value in the page's model." - by adding a hidden input field in your (HTML) form.  Add the code for your view, and the controller action that sits behind it.